# C# Wuapi gives incorrect feature update information

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, wuapi

I use wuapi for scanning and installing updates on windows 10 computers. I find an update on my computer it gives details but i cannot find this update anywhere in windows catalog or even on wsus (I search in all classifications and products )

Title: Feature update to Windows 10, version 20H2
Classification: 3689bdc8-b205-4af4-8d4a-a63924c5e9d5 (Upgrade)
KB: 5004237
Update ID: ff95561b-934d-4f58-af55-cabbdffb1a92

I cannot find this update on windows update catalog or wsus. This KB points Cumulative Update but wuapi gives me classification as Upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The feature updates of Windows 10 are not available on Microsoft Update Catalog website for downloading. They can be deployed via patch management applications like WSUS, SCCM, etc. If you're looking at Microsoft Catalog Update website using your C# code, this is the probable reason why it doesn't list out the same.

If you've configured the `"Upgrade"` classification on WSUS, then kindly perform a manual synchronisation. Hopefully, after a successful sync with Microsoft Update servers, all the feature updates (including v20H2) should reflect in the WSUS inventory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mention WSUS has all this download links and other informations. I decided to go by wsus and sync updates from it. But strange part is when i cannot find update information from any microsoft site about ff95561b-934d-4f58-af55-cabbdffb1a92 this site has this update ready for download https://uupdump.net/known.php?q=19042 

I have no idea how they got this update. I didn't have time to check source code of that application.

Comment: @Cozdemir - I'm not actually sure about how do they download the UUP files from Microsoft Servers and convert it ISO. Need to check the source code for understanding in detail the background action. But, I do know that in its script, it does download from UUP-Dump website and convert to ISO with the help of a tool `Aria2C`. You might want to explore it further...